# GitHub creating 2 merge commits after merging Pull Request

Tags: git, github, merge, pull-request

In this repo when I open a Pull Request and merge it, GitHub is creating 2 merge commits, in the image example i solved some conflicts and merged. I haven`t done any **squash** or **rebase** on the branch `alteracoesPequenas`. Why is this happening?

Image of the two merge commits on git tree

[image: 1]

Comment: Did you resolve the merge conflicts locally or in the GitHub UI? If you did it in the UI, I can see how it might feel like GitHub made that first merge, but actually *you* did that merge, and GH just helped you do it. That's the same thing that would have happened if you had merged `master` into your branch locally on your machine and pushed it back out. This is why I worded [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75331420/184546) the way I did, highlighting the fact that whoever resolved the conflicts created the first merge commit.

Comment: @TTT Yes, i did everything throught the GitHub UI. I used to rebase my branches before pull request, but the commits in the commit tree always ended up being "duplicated"

Comment: If you elect to resolve conflicts by rebasing your branch onto `master`, then you are "rewriting" the commits on your branch and changing their commit IDs.  If you then try to update your PR by pushing your branch, you will get an error saying something to the effect of "the tip of your branch is behind its remote counterpart", and Git suggests that you pull first and then push. If you do what Git suggests, and pull, **that's** what will merge in the old version of your branch with your new one, and cause the duplicate IDs. Instead, *in this case*, you would force push your branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minor correction might make this much clearer:

> when I open a Pull Request and merge it, GitHub is creating 2 merge commits...

Actually, *you* made the first merge commit when you merged `master` into your branch to resolve the conflicts, and GitHub made the second merge commit when you completed the Pull request. This is a common occurrence, and nothing to worry about.

Note from the comments confirming you resolved conflicts in the GitHub UI:

> If you did it in the UI, I can see how it might feel like GitHub made that first merge, but actually *you* did that merge, and GH just helped you do it. That's the same thing that would have happened if you had merged master into your branch locally on your machine and pushed it back out.

If it bothers you, you can probably avoid the first merge commit that you made. To resolve conflicts on your branch before completing a PR you can either merge in the target branch like you did, or you can rebase your branch onto the target branch. With rebase you rewrite your branch such that it appears as though you branched off of the latest `master` right now, and then made all of your commits on top of that. (Which, btw, is why we say you rebase "onto" `master` versus merging `master` "into" your branch.) With rebase your branch will be linear and won't have the initial merge commit.

As for the merge commit that GitHub creates when you complete the PR, this is because of the merge strategy selected, and "merge" is the default option (and perhaps the preferred option of most projects for merges into long-lived shared branches). GitHub offers [2 other options](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/incorporating-changes-from-a-pull-request/about-pull-request-merges#rebase-and-merge-your-pull-request-commits) which are "squash, merge" which will squash all of the changes into a single linear commit, and also "rebase, merge"<sup>1</sup> which will once again rebase your branch onto master like you potentially did to resolve the conflicts. Note if you choose this option, GitHub will rebase your commits again even if your branch is already up to date with `master` and doesn't need it. I assume they do this to avoid confusion caused by sometimes your commit IDs change and other times they don't. Here they always will change.

So to sum this all up:

1. You can avoid the first merge commit by rebasing instead of merging to resolve conflicts.
2. You can avoid the second merge commit by selecting either the squash-merge, or rebase-merge strategies when completing your PR.

My personal preference is rebase to avoid the first merge commit, but still use merge when completing PRs to have one merge commit into `master`.

---

<sup>1</sup> IMHO, "rebase, merge" really ought to be called "rebase, fast-forward". Using the word merge there kind of implies a semi-linear merge which can be achieved by rebasing and then merging with `--no-ff` to force a merge commit. I suppose GH is using "merge" here in the default sense of fast-forward if possible, and in this case it will always be possible. This wording choice would probably be more obvious if GH offered both options, [like Bitbucket does](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/pull-request-merge-strategies-844499235.html).

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is correct and normal. Merging makes a merge commit; that's what a merge is. So:

1. You wanted GitHub to merge `alteracoesPequenas` into `master`, closing the pull request; but GitHub wouldn't do it, because of merge conflicts.
2. So you resolved the conflicts by doing a reverse merge of `master`
   into `alteracoesPequenas`. (Merge commit)
3. Then you were able to have GitHub merge
   `alteracoesPequenas` into `master`, which was your goal. (Merge commit)

All very right
and proper and completely standard. Don't worry, be happy.

**NOTE** Another psychological issue here may be GitHub's way of presenting what happened. This is not a topological diagram, it's just a flat list of commits reachable from `master`. The first merge commit you did isn't really "on" `master` in the sense you probably think of it; it's "on" `alteracoesPequenas`. Only one merge commit is "on" `master`, namely the merge commit that closed the pull request.